# ctypes.memmove() in-place with an str argument, without converting to bytes

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to modify Python `str` in-place. How can I do this using `ctypes.memmove` without converting to `bytes` first? My goal is to save memory and converting to `bytes` will make a copy of the string which makes it pointless to use ctypes in the first place.

I tried converting to `c_wchar_p` but this doesn't do anything to `newstr` instance

```py
    dest = POINTER(c_char)(c_char.from_address(addressof(ctypes.c_wchar_p(newstr))))
    source = POINTER(c_char)(c_char.from_address(addressof(ctypes.c_wchar_p(newstr)) + 1))
    ctypes.memmove(
        dest,
        source,
        length - 1,
    )
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the data source? Why can't it be read directly into `bytes`? Do you have no control over how it is read?

Comment: If you really meant a Python string, then it's Unicode and therefore doesn't have a memory / bytes representation you could do anything useful on **before encoding it**, which is the step that turns it into a bytes object. So if you don't want to do that, you will need to read it in as `bytes` right from the start, like @blhsing said.

Comment: “I need to modify Python str in-place”. Python strings are immutable, so that is a bad idea, and so are bytes, so you’re going to need to make a copy anyway.

Comment: You can create a writable bytes buffer with `ctypes.create_string_buffer` or a writable wchar_t buffer with `create_unicode_buffer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> import sys
>>> s = "Hello World"
>>> s_mem = (ctypes.c_byte * len(s)).from_address(id(s) + sys.getsizeof(s) - len(s) - 1)
>>> ctypes.memmove(s_mem, b"Howdy", 5)
139669939550304
>>> s
'Howdy World'
```

**References:**

- [PEP 393](https://peps.python.org/pep-0393/)
- [GitHub: python/cpython/Include/cpython/unicodeobject.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/cpython/unicodeobject.h)

Comment: While this “works” it violates the immutability of a Python string and should never be used in production code.