# In-place way of trimming & removing extra whitespace from a string

Tags: python, ctypes

Looking for a way to remove extra whitespace from a large python string (100MB+) without making copies. Tried using `ctypes` but it seems like you have to convert the string to `bytes` for `ctypes.memmove` to work.

I need a function `remove_extra_whitespaces` that can do this in O(1) memory

```py
>> a = '  hello   world'
>> a = remove_extra_whitespaces(a)
>> a == 'hello world'
True
```

Is there a library or something else that I can use for this task?

Comment: `.strip()` removes leading and trailing whitespace but does not affect any in-between

Comment: I highly doubt there is a O(1) solution.

Comment: I'm talking O(1) memory, i.e. no memory allocation, not runtime. Runtime is obv at least O(n)

Comment: I can do this in C, why not using ctypes? Maybe if I wrote a C module?

Comment: I am wondering if someone has already done that

Comment: Why do you have 2 questions? Isn't the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73163042/4788546.

Comment: That one is about ctypes and this is about alternatives to ctypes approach

Comment: Why is *CTypes* needed, and *Python* native functions can't be used? But regardless *remove\_extra\_whitespaces* implementation, I don't think it's doable as strings are immutable in *Python*

Answer (score 0):

According to [Python str docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str): Strings are immutable sequences of Unicode code points. There is also no mutable string type.

I would suggest you to try to get `bytes` or `bytearray` in the first place. That 100MB+ string has to come from somewhere.

1. From file you can read `bytes` or incrementaly create `bytearray` (`a += b`)
2. From socket you can read `bytes` on lower level. HTTP or other protocol libraries support reading `bytes`.

Best solution would be to get your string as `bytearray` and then you can make operations without new allocations, closest to C style.

```py
import re

whitespace_re = re.compile(b'\s{2,}')

def remove_extra_whitespaces(a):
    match = re.search(b'^\s+', a)
    # strip whitespace from start
    a[:match.end()] = b''
    i = 0
    match = whitespace_re.search(a, i)
    while match:
        # replaces spaces with one, but CPU will copy rest of a
        a[match.start():match.end()] = b' '
        i = match.start() + 1  # +1 for space
        match = whitespace_re.search(a, i)
    # strip whitespace from end
    if a[-1:] == b' ':
        a.pop()
    # you don't need to return it because original bytearray is updated
    return a

a = remove_extra_whitespaces(bytearray(b'  aaa*100MB  bbb   '))
# a == bytearray(b'aaa*100MB bbb')
```

Since Python 3.8 you can use following syntax:

```py
while (match := whitespace_re.search(a, i)):
    ...
```

Algorithm could be made more CPU efficient by avoiding to copy rest of bytes in each whitespace and copying only non-whitespace characters. Truncating the bytearray to final lenght in the and as you would in C program.